# Comparing two lists with multiple conditions

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have two different lists of same type. I wanted to compare both lists and need to get the values which are not matched.
List of class:

```
public class pre
{
public int id {get; set;}
public datetime date {get; set;}
public int sID {get; set;}
}
```

Two lists :

```
List<pre> pre1 = new List<pre>();
List<pre> pre2 = new List<pre>();
```

Query which I wrote to get the unmatched values:

```
var preResult = pre1.where(p1 => !pre
                    .any(p2 => p2.id == p1.id && p2.date == p1.date && p2.sID == p1sID));
```

But the result is wrong here. I am getting all the values in pre1.

Answer (score 4):

Here is solution :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var pre1 = new List<pre>()
        {
               new pre {id = 1, date =DateTime.Now.Date, sID=1 },
               new pre {id = 7, date = DateTime.Now.Date, sID = 2 },
               new pre {id = 9, date = DateTime.Now.Date, sID = 3 },
               new pre {id = 13, date = DateTime.Now.Date, sID = 4 },        
               // ... etc ...
        };
        var pre2 = new List<pre>()
        {
               new pre {id = 1, date =DateTime.Now.Date, sID=1 },
               // ... etc ...
        };

        var preResult = pre1.Where(p1 => !pre2.Any(p2 => p2.id == p1.id && p2.date == p1.date && p2.sID == p1.sID)).ToList();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Note:Property date contain the date and the time part will be 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some typos and tested your code with sensible values, and your code would correctly select unmatched records. As [prabhakaran S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416884/414076) mentions, perhaps your date values include time components that differ. You will need to check your data and decide how to proceed.

However, a better way to select unmatched records from one list compared against another would be to utilize a left join technique common to working with relational databases, which you can also do in Linq against in-memory collections. It will scale better as the sizes of your inputs grow.

```
var preResult = from p1 in pre1 
                join p2 in pre2 
                on new { p1.id, p1.date, p1.sID } 
                equals new { p2.id, p2.date, p2.sID } into grp
                from item in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where item == null 
                select p1;
```